# Magento cannot upload category images

Tags: php, image, magento, upload, categories

I have installed Magento 1.8.1 and runs smoothly using the Zonda magento theme.
I am able to upload all kinds of images in all kinds of places (products, favicons, placeholders etc).
What doesn't work are the category images, thumbnail AND image.

Anyone has any idea? Everyone seems to have the problem that either no image upload works or all the uploads work.

Please help me out! :)

Comment: Do you get an error in `var/log`?

Comment: Yes but no error there, seems like it doesn't reach a function then?